# Data is not coming from firestore in Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Angular and I am learning about services. I am creating a desk reservation app and I am trying to fetch data from firestore. This is how my service looks like.

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Reservation } from '../models/Reservation';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ReservationService {
  reservationCollection!: AngularFirestoreCollection<Reservation>;
  reservation!: Observable<Reservation[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.reservationCollection = this.afs.collection('Building').doc('Floors').collection('Floor1', (ref) =>
      ref.orderBy('order', 'asc')
    );
  }

  getSeats(): Observable<Reservation[]> {
    this.reservation = this.reservationCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map((changes: any) => {
      return changes.map((action: any) => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Reservation;
        data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return data
      })
    }))
    return this.reservation;
  }
}
```

And this is the ts file

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReservationService } from 'src/app/services/reservation.service';
import { Reservation } from 'src/app/models/Reservation';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservation',
  templateUrl: './reservation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservation.component.css']
})
export class ReservationComponent implements OnInit {
  seats: Reservation[] = [];

  constructor(
    private reservation: ReservationService,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth
    ) {
      console.log(this.seats)
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reservation.getSeats().subscribe((seats) => {
      this.seats = seats
    })
  }
}
```

The service works just fine and when I put the data in the console it sometimes shows ok. But when I try to set up the seats property (this.seats = seats) it does not get updated and is just an empty array. I have a feeling it has something to do with the service being async, but I don't know how to correct it with firestore. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not waiting for the `getSeats` function in your service to return anything before it completes. As you expected, this is because your function is asynchronous.

Modify your getSeats function in your service like this to return an observable of the data:

```ts
  async getSeats() {
    this.reservation = await this.reservationCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map((changes: any) => {
      return changes.map((action: any) => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as any;
        data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return data
      })
    }))

    return this.reservation;
  }
```

And then in your component change your seats declaration to be an Observable:

```ts
  seats: Observable<any[]> | undefined;
```

And then change your ngOnInit to this:

```ts
  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.seats = await this.reservation.getSeats();

    this.seats.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

The subscribe in this scenario is just for your own benefit when debugging so you can view the data. In practice, you will probably be iterating over each seat in your HTML template using an ngFor loop.

PS, you'll want to add your reservation model back in. I removed it because I don't know what your data looks like :)